# Federate authorization requests with Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm looking to leverage the spring authorization server (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server).

I need to federate authorization requests to backing IDPs based on a set of rules. Is there some documentation or suggested entry points to where this could be implemented?

Rules could include:

- By domain of the user name (first.last@**some-domain**.com)
- By relying party client id
- IDP hint query parameter as part of authorization request

EDITS BELOW - providing more detail and context to the problem:

Many applications will interact solely with the Spring authorization server via OIDC to authenticate users.  Some users may have their credentials managed by a separate authorization server, e.g., google or facebook.  In these cases, I would like to federate the authentication via OIDC to the specific identity provider.

Example Workflow:

```
Application --oidc--> Spring Authorization Server --oidc-> Google
```

There could be many ways that we could determine:

1. If we need to federate authentication
2. Which IDP to federate authentication to

We will support authorization code grant for user-driven OAuth flows.  So every authentication request will start with a call to the authorize endpoint.

For example:

`http://auth-server:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=messaging-client&scope=......`

After this request, I'd like to configure the Spring Authorization Server to make the determination of where to federate the authentication if required.

potential options:

1. Have the user enter their username, then federate to an associated IDP
2. Look at a query parameter hint.  For example: /oauth2/authorize?client_id=messaging-client&**idp=google**

Please let me know if I can clarify anymore.

Comment: Regarding "I need to federate authorization requests to backing IDPs" ... do you mean you need to federate login to multiple identity providers? It's not clear to me why you need to federate authorization requests. Can you provide more detail on your use case.

Comment: @JoeGrandja Yes, I need to federate user logins to separate identity providers depending on different rules.  I have added more context above.  Thanks.

Comment: We have an existing issue that would provide a sample on how to achieve federated login. I'll try to find time over the next couple of weeks to provide the sample.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/106

Answer (score 0):

See the [Federated Identity sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver).

While I don't have an example of all of the possible ways you could detect which 3rd party IDP to direct the flow to, this branch does have one example: Look at a query parameter hint. See the [FederatedIdentityAuthenticationEntryPoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/5ab82f83cb8d3168e24a5e743826f2385c140cd4/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/security/FederatedIdentityAuthenticationEntryPoint.java#L43) for an example of how to do this.

The idea is that once the `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint is requested via the browser, an unauthenticated user will be asked to authenticate, which triggers the `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. This is where we would probably want to detect the hint, or take any other action to initiate the appropriate flow or login page. Since the `client_id` is also usually available in that request, you could have multiple ways of responding to this request depending on your needs.

It's best to have a fallback though, so that the server responds in the "default way" when any of these mechanisms cannot proceed for whatever reason, so the implementation delegates to `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` and redirects to a login page. This also happens to allow you to combine form login with federated login!